# How to set button not clickable on React native ios

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm currently trying to set the button not clickable when a number is less than 1. The "disabled" attribute works as expected for **android** but for ios it doesn't seem to work.

Do I need to add any additional code in xcode for it to work with ios?

```
const ButtonPaynow = styled(Button)`
  padding: 1px;
  fontSize: 13px;
  overflow:hidden;
`

 <ButtonPaynow
    disabled={!form.formState.isValid || total < 1.0}
    onPress={onPressPayNow}
    text={`${payNowButton}`}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like adding the  tag helps to stop the button from firing based on the condition mentioned which is just what I needed.

```
<TouchableOpacity disabled={!form.formState.isValid || total < 1.0} onPress={onPressPayNow}>
   <ButtonPaynow
     text={`${payNowButton}`}
   />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Not the cleanest piece of code but looking to clean it up.